# Crystal Report 1 field should be at the same line

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

Im using Crystal Reports,and I have an output like this:

```
     NumberId         ART_No          InkColor
     ------------------------------------------
     0010             23003             BLUE
     0010             23003             RED
     0010             23003             GREEN
     0013             23004             ORANGE
     0013             23004             PINK
     0013             23004             WHITE
     0015             23007             GREEN
     0015             23007             PINK
```

Is there any possible way how can I make the output (in Crystal Reports) be like this even not using SQL Script:

```
     NumberId         ART_No          InkColor
     ------------------------------------------
     0010             23003             BLUE, RED, GREEN
     0013             23004             ORANGE, PINK, WHITE
     0015             23007             GREEN, PINK
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do a few things to achieve that.

1. Create a group for `NumberId`.
2. Suppress the Group Header.
3. Create a FormulaField; we'll call it `@ColorReset`.  It should contain the following code:

   ```
   WhilePrintingRecords;
   stringVar Colors := "";
   ```

   Place this in your group header.  This will reset the `Colors` stringVar every time the Group Header is hit.
4. Suppress the Detail section.
5. Create another FormulaField; we'll call it `@ColorAppend`.  It should concatenate the values like this:

   ```
   WhilePrintingRecords;
   stringVar Colors := Colors + ", " + {YourTable.InkColor};
   ```

   Place this in your detail section.  This will build your color string every time the Detail section loops.
6. Create one more FormulaField to show the colors, called `@ColorsShow`.  It will display the colors like this:

   ```
   WhilePrintingRecords;
   StringVar Colors;

   RIGHT(Colors, LEN(Colors) - 2);    // Strip off the leading comma and space
   ```

   Place this in your group footer, along with the `NumberId` and `ART_No`

---

Your end result should be:

```
---------- Group Header 1 ----------
/////////// @ColorReset ////////////

------------- Details --------------
////////// @ColorAppend ////////////

---------- Group Footer 1 ----------
[NumberId] [ART_No] [@ColorsShow]
```

It looks a little initmidating, but it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: This comes with one caveat:  some versions of Crystal Reports may blow up if you try to concatenate 255 or more characters.  Depending on your version, you may hit a concatenation limit.